# Should bug reports be closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

It sounds like from [Brandon's comment here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/79/weird-sql-error-after-a-new-matrix-field-type-is-added#comment74_79) that bug reports should be submitted directly to Craft Support.

> ...please contact us directly when you run into bugs such as
>   PHP/MySQL errors. Preferably through the Get Help widget on your
>   Dashboard (which can include a DB backup), or you can email
>   support@buildwithcraft.com.

With that in mind, should bug report-type questions (PHP or MySQL errors), be allowed at all? Or simply closed as off-topic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Bugs are better served and corrected by Pixel & Tonic. While many of us more PHP-experienced users can probably fix it, it would be a waste of our energies since we can't distribute the fix to others like Pixel & Tonic can. Not to mention you can send a DB backup to them for better diagnosis, and they are wicked smart and quick to fix issues.

Comment: My biggest concern with the no bug reports rule is that in many cases a beginner user may not know whether their issue is just user error or actually a bug report. There are many times when I, as a fairly advanced developer, spend time hunting around before realizing I've hit a bug. I really wish there was a way we could keep questions that indicate that symptoms of a bug, so that users can easily see that there is a documented fix.

Comment: @Jeremy Maybe a "Common Bugfix"-Guide would be a solution to this?

Comment: Sure, sometimes it’s not clear. If you’re getting a PHP/MySQL error though, it should be pretty clear that’s not intended behavior.

Comment: I think Brandon's quote (or something similar) from the question should be placed in the sidebar to avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: I think we also have to remember not to be assholes, particularly when new folks aren't sure how/what to post. Kind people have helped me learn from my embarrassing questions, so I edit with vigor and pay it forward.

Comment: Isn't this part of being a community though? If it's considered off-topic, we can simply explain in the reason for being off-topic. Better yet, we can even give possible next steps. For bugs, we simply say, "This sounds like a bug! You should use the support form in the CP."

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any disagreement, I just mean that it's better to close gently rather than slam. *Because* it's being part of a community. "Closed as off-topic" can seem pretty harsh to a new member if a bunch of people voted on it and nobody mentioned why. Google+ isn't nearly the same platform, but it doesn't have the same hard edges either. Apologies if I'm being unclear; that's kind of what I do here.