# How do I submit a bug/issue with Craft?

Tags: discussion

I've come across some issues in the past and I would like to submit them for review. However, I've Google'd etc and can't find the right place to do this - anyone?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should address bug reports to P+T. This can either be done directly from the dashboard of your Control Panel (Get Help widget) or you write an email to support@craftcms.com.

Another way is to create an [issue](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues) in the public Craft 3 [Github repo](https://github.com/craftcms/cms).  It's worth searching there to make sure there isn't an existing issue already.  This is a good way to let others know about your issues or to get more of a discussion started about it. I have yet seen anything posted in there getting no attention from the P+T team.

You could always link to an existing question that you started here, that later turned out being rather a bug/issue than sth. the community can help you with ;)

There is a question about how to handle [questions concerning bug reports](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/should-bug-reports-be-closed-as-off-topic) on the Craft Meta Stack Exchange site.

Comment: This answer probably needs updating now that the G+ page is producing a 404.

Answer (score 8):

If it's a bug report, then the Get Help widget would be the best route, as it allows you to include your log files and other information.

If it's more of a suggestion, then support@craftcms.com would be your best bet.

Comment: Great call mentioning the Get Help attachments... If you really think it's a bug, sending your log files, database backup, template files, or any other attachment (ie: screenshots) would be super-helpful for P&T to diagnose the problem!